# unable to extract text from span tag using Beautifulsoup and Request

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrap posts from this online forum. https://csn.cancer.org/categories/prostate
All post seems to be in span tags.

I used the code below to scrap the posts.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = f"https://csn.cancer.org/categories/prostate"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')
ps = soup.findAll('span',attrs ={ 'class':"css-yjh1h7-TruncatedText-styles-truncated"})
for p in ps:
    print(p.text)
```

I got nothing.  from the span ('class':"css-yjh1h7-TruncatedText-styles-truncated"), I'm not able to extract anything.

However, what's puzzling me is that if I take part of the html code from the website and did the following:

```
html ='''  <div class="css-e9znss-ListItem-styles-item"><div class="css-1flthw6-ListItem-styles-iconContainer"><div class="css-n9xrp8-ListItem-styles-icon"><div class="css-7yur4m-DiscussionList-classes-userIcon"><a aria-current="false" href="https://csn.cancer.org/profile/336163/PhoenixM" tabindex="0" data-link-type="legacy"><div class="css-1eztffh-userPhotoStyles-medium css-11wwpgq-userPhotoStyles-root isOpen"><img title="PhoenixM" alt="User: &quot;PhoenixM&quot;" height="200" width="200" src="https://w6.vanillicon.com/v2/62fd0812499add3e38f8e90eee3af967.svg" class="css-10y567c-userPhotoStyles-photo" loading="lazy"></div></a></div></div></div><div class="css-2guvez-ListItem-styles-contentContainer"><div class="css-1kxjkhx-ListItem-styles-titleContainer"><h3 class="css-glebqx-ListItem-styles-title"><a aria-current="false" href="https://csn.cancer.org/discussion/327814/brachytherapy" class="css-ojxxy9-ListItem-styles-titleLink-DiscussionList-classes-title" tabindex="0" data-link-type="legacy"><span class="css-yjh1h7-TruncatedText-styles-truncated">Brachytherapy</span></a></h3></div><div class="css-1y6ygw7-ListItem-styles-metaWrapContainer"><div class="css-5swiwf-ListItem-styles-metaDescriptionContainer"><p class="css-1ggegep-ListItem-styles-description"><span class="css-yjh1h7-TruncatedText-styles-truncated">I have recently been diagnosed with locally advanced prostate cancer. Gleason 9 stage 4a. My cancer has spread outside my prostate to a very enlarged lymph node in my pelvic region. I’m currently taki…</span></p><div class="css-1uyxq88-Metas-styles-root css-h3lbxm-ListItem-styles-metasContainer"><div class="css-1a607mt-Metas-styles-meta">135 views</div><div class="css-1a607mt-Metas-styles-meta">6 comments</div><div class="css-1a607mt-Metas-styles-meta">0 point</div><div class="css-1a607mt-Metas-styles-meta">Started by <a aria-current="false" href="https://csn.cancer.org/profile/336163/PhoenixM" class="css-1unw87s-Metas-styles-metaLink" tabindex="0" data-link-type="legacy">PhoenixM</a></div><div class="css-1a607mt-Metas-styles-meta">Most recent by <a aria-current="false" href="https://csn.cancer.org/profile/285710/Steve1961" class="css-1unw87s-Metas-styles-metaLink" tabindex="0" data-link-type="legacy">Steve1961</a></div><div class="css-1a607mt-Metas-styles-meta"><time datetime="2024-03-22T01:59:58+00:00" title="Thursday, March 21, 2024 at 9:59 PM">Mar 21, 2024</time></div><div class="css-1a607mt-Metas-styles-meta"><a aria-current="false" href="https://csn.cancer.org/categories/prostate" class="css-1unw87s-Metas-styles-metaLink" tabindex="0" data-link-type="legacy"> Prostate Cancer </a></div></div></div></div></div><div class="css-1pv9k2p-ListItem-styles-actionsContainer"></div></div> '''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

# Parse the HTML with BeautifulSoup
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')

ps = soup.findAll('span',attrs ={ 'class':"css-yjh1h7-TruncatedText-styles-truncated"})

for p in ps:
    print(p.text)
```

I was able to extract the post content.  Can anyone help me understand why I could not extract anything from the site url?  What did I do wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've looked for `css-yjh1h7` in the inspection of the website and wasn't able to find anything, are you sure that html you've posted comes from the same website?

Comment: The website is filled with Javascript, BeautifulSoup can't parse that, it will only receive the DOM as it requests returns is. You'lll need some tool like Selenium to scrape data that is inserted using javascript.

Comment: With > 10k rep you should be aware of requirements for posting self-contained questions. Create a [mre] of the page's HTML and include it in your question, not a link to an external site.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to load the data from the embedded JSON string that is found inside the page:

```py
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://csn.cancer.org/categories/prostate"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = soup.select_one('[data-react="DiscussionListModule"]')["data-props"]
data = json.loads(data)

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "apiParams": {
        "rand": "5Y5ZJ48BKR"
    },
    "discussions": [
        {
            "discussionID": 324401,
            "type": "discussion",
            "name": "Some tips from CSN",
            "excerpt": "Welcome to the CSN! Below are some tips to help you get started following and posting on the boards. You can follow your preferred discussion board to get notifications of new topics and comments. To follow a board, navigate to your preferred board and then select the bell at the top, followed by your notification\u2026",
            "categoryID": 126,
            "dateInserted": "2021-12-01T22:15:59+00:00",
            "dateUpdated": "2023-12-18T14:32:44+00:00",
            "dateLastComment": "2021-12-01T22:15:59+00:00",
            "insertUserID": 231489,
            "insertUser": {
                "userID": 231489,
                "name": "CSNSupportTeam",
                "url": "https://csn.cancer.org/profile/CSNSupportTeam",
                "photoUrl": "https://us.v-cdn.net/6035652/uploads/userpics/OIBYPVTDVA21/nMI8TZCFNO605.jpg",
                "dateLastActive": "2024-03-22T20:35:00+00:00",
                "banned": 0,
                "punished": 0,
                "private": false,
                "label": ""
            },

...
```

Answer (score 0):

The required data is present inside `noscript` tag. That's why we are not able to parse it directly. I identifed a pattern and split the response to get the required html page source. The below code snippet works fine.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = f"https://csn.cancer.org/categories/prostate"
response = requests.get(url)

try:
        # Extracting html page source present in the noscript tag to parse and extract the required data
        noscript_value = response.text.split('noscript><div class="pageBox"')[1].split("</div></noscript>")[0].strip()
except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        noscript_value = None

soup = bs(noscript_value, 'html.parser')

ps = soup.findAll('li')
for p in ps:
        print(p.text.strip())
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Some tips from CSN
Welcome to the CSN! Below are some tips to help you get started following and posting on the boards. You can follow your preferred discussion board to get notifications
 of new topics and comments. To follow a board, navigate to your preferred board and then select the bell at the top, followed by your notification…
Second Biopsy results
Last November at 67 after an MRI my first fusion biopsy was done transrectally at local hospital. It indicated (as far as I could figure) a single tumor residing in the
 right side of my prostate. I had a NM bone scan in January which did not show any bony metastases. Also a Prolaris test which indicated for single modal…
Brachytherapy
I have recently been diagnosed with locally advanced prostate cancer. Gleason 9 stage 4a. My cancer has spread outside my prostate to a very enlarged lymph node in my p
elvic region. I’m currently taking Orgovyx +Abiraterone and my Radiologist is recommending IMRT. Ive been doing research that suggests brachytherapy…
.
.
.
Benign biopsy. Confirm MDX test results: 21%< =G6; 15%>=G7
I had a MRI fusion transperineal biopsy. 26 cores benign. My urologist ordered a Confirm MDX test. Results show: Likelihood of prostate cancer on repeat biopsy: 36% 21% likelihood of detecting Gleason score < = 6 cancer 15% likelihood of detecting Gleason score >=7 cancer It is recommending for a second biopsy. I guess I…
PSA Value at 0.54 on 1/24/24
I had Prostate Cancer in 2018 and had radiation treatments all was good but now my value is all over the place since then on 11/17/21 V @ 0.7, on 3/15/22, 1.84 on 3/30/23 0.38, on 8/7/23 0.26, 1/24/24 0.54 is this common?
```

Answer (score 0):

The point here is that you are inspecting the source code of the dynamically rendered version by the browser via your browser's devoloper tools, but `requests` only works with the static response.

Therefore, always check the `response` / `soup` first to see whether all expected elements are present or are present in the expected from.

The static variant only returns an unordered list of link and paragraph entries, so adapt your localisation strategy accordingly.

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = f"https://csn.cancer.org/categories/prostate"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')

data = []
for e in soup.select('ul.linkList li'):
    data.append({
        'url':e.a.get('href'),
        'title':e.a.text,
        'content':e.p.text
    })

data
```

Output:

```
[{'url': 'https://csn.cancer.org/discussion/324401/some-tips-from-csn',
  'title': 'Some tips from CSN',
  'content': 'Welcome to the CSN! Below are some tips to help you get started following and posting on the boards. You can follow your preferred discussion board to get notifications of new topics and comments. To follow a board, navigate to your preferred board and then select the bell at the top, followed by your notification…'},
 {'url': 'https://csn.cancer.org/discussion/327774/second-biopsy-results',
  'title': 'Second Biopsy results',
  'content': 'Last November at 67 after an MRI my first fusion biopsy was done transrectally at local hospital. It indicated (as far as I could figure) a single tumor residing in the right side of my prostate. I had a NM bone scan in January which did not show any bony metastases. Also a Prolaris test which indicated for single modal…'},
 ...
{'url': 'https://csn.cancer.org/discussion/327732/psa-value-at-0-54-on-1-24-24',
  'title': 'PSA Value at 0.54 on 1/24/24',
  'content': 'I had Prostate Cancer in 2018 and had radiation treatments all was good but now my value is all over the place since then on 11/17/21 V @ 0.7, on 3/15/22, 1.84 on 3/30/23 0.38, on 8/7/23 0.26, 1/24/24 0.54 is this common?'}]
```